# Problem with shortcut on the RStudio new version

Tags: rstudio, shortcut

I am using the new version of RStudio since today and when I tried to change my shortcut to "Run Selected Line" to 'Ctrl + R' it doesn't appear the R it appears a square: Ctrl + ☐

It happend with you too? I've been using R since 2014 and it never happend before...

Best Regards!

Comment: I think it is more appropriate to file this as an issue on their GH repo.

Comment: yes, but try to change any shortcut to ctrl + r, it's doesn't work...

Comment: I understand, I see it too. I just don't understand how you expect the SO community to solve it, other than to file an issue to the RStudio GH repo.

Comment: yep, you are right.

Comment: https://github.com/rstudio/rstudio/issues/6129